# Hide /path from search engines, except for /path/that-i-want-indexed

Tags: seo, web-crawlers, robots.txt

In our robots.txt we have something like

```
User-agent: *
Disallow: /v6.0
Disallow: /v5.8
Disallow: /v5.7
Disallow: /v5.5
Disallow: /v5.1
Disallow: /v5.0
```

Which properly prevents search engines from crawling any of our URLs prefixed by `/v6.0`, `/v5.8` etc... However, there are certain pages within those disallowed URLs that we do want indexed, such as `/v6.0/i-want-this-page-indexable`

Is doing such a thing possible? If so, what would be the appropriate syntax?

Answer (score 2):

To allow a more *specific* URL you can use the `Allow` directive (supported by all major search engine bots). For example:

```
User-agent: *
Allow: /v6.0/i-want-this-page-indexable
Disallow: /v6.0
Disallow: /v5.8
Disallow: /v5.7
Disallow: /v5.5
Disallow: /v5.1
Disallow: /v5.0
```

The order of these directives doesn't strictly matter for *most* search engine bots (including Google) as the most *specific* URL-path (by length) will *win*. However, for some search engine bots the first matching URL-path wins, so the `Allow` directive should go before the `Disallow` directive where there is a conflicting URL-path.